# What is the internal mechanism when a Keras custom loss function access a global variable of python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Whether does a Keras custom loss function  accept global python variable?

I am building my own Keras custom loss function, which only accepts `y_true` and `y_pred` as arguments.But the loss function is quite complex and it depends on other variables.Currently in my implementation,the loss function just directly uses global variables in the same python code script.After training the model,if I want to use the model to do prediction,and then those global variables in the python environment will be changed. My question is that,do I need to compile the model again,to guarantee that the model has been updated with the latest version of those external global variables?

```
Rlist=....

def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    z = 0.0
    #Rlist is the global variable 
    for j in Rlist:
        z = z  +K.log(K.sum(K.exp(K.gather(y_pred,j[0])))) \
        - K.log(K.sum(K.exp(K.gather(y_pred,j))))
    z = -z 
    return z
#below build the model and compile it with loss=custom_loss
model=...
model.compile(loss=custom_loss,....
model.fit(x=train_x,y=train_y,...)
#Rlist=...  update Rlist which is adaptive to test dataset
#Do I need to recompile in the code below,or whether Rlist is updated
#in custom_loss when it is called?
model.predict(x=test_x,y=test_y,...)
```

In my loss function(actually this is the loss function for cox proportional hazard model),the loss is not additive among loss values for each samples.
`Rlist` is a global variable in the python environment of my Keras code
my question is that,after training the model,if I change this `Rlist` for
the test dataset,will Keras automatically update the `Rlist`,or it uses the old version of this variable `Rlist` when it compiles and builds the computation graph?

Is there any explanation that if I directly refer to a global variable from python environment in the loss function,then what will happen when Tensorflow builds its computation graph?
I know it's not a goop practice to use global variable.Better  suggestions are also recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "python environment of my Keras code"? If you set the Rlist variable in your code while training to [1,2,3]. And then change it to [3,2,1] in prediction/production mode, you custom loss will see the [3,2,1] variable.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, i suppose this could work: 
A) Create a real ENV_Variable with RList
B) Create a JSON File with your RList (that way, you'll be able to use your RList data in production mode on server or cloud).
C) Create a Dict in your code like

```
RList={
    'train': [1,2,3], 
    'test':[3,2,1], 
    'production':[4,5,6]
}
```